# Tolerance interval for lognormal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $X$ be an observation from a lognormal distribution of known mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

What is the probability that $X$ lies within $\mu\pm c\sigma$, for a given $c>0$?

(I believe that is called a tolerance interval, but not being a statistician, please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: What have you attempted to solve the problem?

Comment: I have googled the question, and it is surprisingly difficult to get an answer. I am not a statistician so I have neither the skill nor the inclination to solve the problem myself. I just need a correspondence table between c=1,2,3 and the probability. Something like the 3-sigma rule for the normal distribution would be fine.